# Lock(file) for write between pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application that uses an XML file to store certain data that does not need to be in the DB. This file, while rarely, might be written to between pages at the same time. This creates an issue, most probably causing one of the pages to crash. I was wondering if there is a way to have a page render wait until the other is done writing to the file.

I am not sure if I can assume that every page render runs in its own thread; if it does, then can I halt that thread like a lock() command to wait for the resource to be available. If so, how can I implement a lock() on a file (since its not a memory segment)?

If its not threaded or I cannot use lock(), what other ways are there to make sure that the file is written to, but if someone else is using that file, it can wait for the file to be available?

There are a lot of methods of managing write order and rights but for this it is simple; if you came second, you will write in after the other person is done. I am not so concerned with write collisions at this point, but concurrent writing is something that needs to be addressed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should still store it in a DB. This will solve the concurrency issues and also keep it atomic in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I suggest you to use database and implement `optimistic` or `pessimistic` concurrency, depending on your needs.

Comment: Why do you assume something will 'crash'? Please elaborate. Don't solve problems that you don't have.

Comment: Have you ever tried opening a file twice and writing to it from the second stream?

Comment: I do it all the time. What about you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's from a single machine, you could use a `Semaphore` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx:

```
private static Semaphore _fileSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "myFileGlobalSemaphore");

// later...

try
{
    _fileSemaphore.WaitOne();
    // do stuff..
}
finally
{
    _fileSemaphore.Release();
}
```

That's kind of like a system-wide lock.  Not great though, would suggest a DB.  Plus, other things might cause file access to fail.  You could implement something which creates a `FileStream` with the appropriate locking mode, which will fail if you try to open for writing by two sources, but it won't do a `lock`-like scenario (which uses the `Monitor` class internally)

Btw: "does not need to be stored in the DB".  The fact you're asking this question suggests it really should be.  If that's a pain to implement, you might want to rethink your data access strategy.  Stuff like Entity Framework w/ Code First makes it very easy to "chuck" stuff in the DB.

Comment: It really depends on the implementation. A lot of it has to do with potability and things short app settings can be held in a file instead. It reduces the amount of hits to the database and it is one less thing to port if the application needs to be duplicated on another system.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Running some more tests (on mono), I'm not so sure this is the best approach.

I didn't manage to crash anything, but execution just pauses after `Run()`, for a few seconds, prior to yielding back to caller. So I suspect that's not a good sign in favor of this code snip.

That being said, the tested scenario is far from realistic.

---

Another option is to open the file in `FileShare.ReadWrite` mode, and let the OS care about lockings.

```
    public void Run()
    {
        var file = @"/home/me/test.txt";
        var threads = new Thread[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            threads[j] = new Thread( s => { 
            Console.WriteLine("thread " + j + " is running...");
            using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                   FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("thread " + j + " is holding the file!");
                var data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello, I'm stream " + j);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }});    
        }   

        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Start();

        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Join();

        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(file));
    }
```

Output:

```
thread 1 is running...
thread 0 is running...
thread 2 is running...
thread 2 is holding the file!
thread 1 is holding the file!
thread 0 is holding the file!
hello, I'm stream 0
```

Answer (score -2):

Use some global lock object. For example add to your global.asax.cs:

```
public static readonly object FileLock = new Object();
```

Then in your pages use:

```
lock(YourApplicationClass.FileLock)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Note, this only works if you only have one AppDomain (i.e. only one worker process)

Comment: Also: he says he can't assure that each access runs in its own thread.  If you try to lock on the same object on the same thread, it won't stop you

Comment: What I meant by that, is that I am not familiar enough with the ASPX app pools to determine if in fact, each page is executed on its own thread. I have tried googling it without any results.

Comment: Is it actually possible for a single thread to enter a critical section twice without leaving it inbetween? If yes, please give an example.

Comment: I phrased my question badly. What I ment was, is it possible for a single thread to execute the same method twice at the same time? If this isn't the case, which I assume, then the `lock()` in my answer won't be a Problem.

Comment: The problem is, this won't work when there are multiple appDomains running the same site. For example, during recycling, the last request of the old appDomain will be running at the same time the next incoming request is handled by the new appDomain. This type of lock does *not* protect against concurrent access in such a situation.